# Outlook interop: how to make application work with both version 2007 and 2010

Tags: outlook, interop

I have created a small application to send emails via Outlook. The application opens an Outlook mail item with various pre-configured templates. 
Now, the application was first build for Outlook 2010 using the Interop version 14. When testing on Outlook 2007, the application fails to create the required MailItem. I was assuming that the Interop would be backwards compatible, but that doesn't to be the case. 
I have already tried using the Interop v12 instead, but then the application doesn't work on version 2010.

How can I make this application work with both Outllok 2007 and 2010.

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop using the lowest supported version of Outlook (2007).
What exactly does not work when running under Outlook 2010 when you are using the 2007 interop?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Dmitry. So, if I understand correctly, you are saying I should use the Interop for Outlook 2007 (v12)? I have tried that and when I run the application unter Outlook 2010 I get the error message:
Error when accessing Outlook: Could not load COM-class factory for component with CLSID .... due to the following error: ....
(my rough backtranslation from German; the ... are some cryptic strings).

Comment: Please post the full error message and the relevent snippet of your code that raises it. Also, what is the bitness of your app, Outlook, and Windows?

Comment: I am working on Win7 64bit with Outlook 2010. The app crashes at the following line: 
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    ...
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

The error message is: "Could not load COM-class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-C000-0000000000046} due to the following error: 8008005"

Comment: 0x80080005 is CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE - this most likely happens if you Outlook under a differemt security context. Is Outlook or your code running as an admin? See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/870d6093-a7fb-4431-a38f-1896ce4cf963/failing-to-create-an-email-with-outlook-interop-when-outlook-has-been-opened-by-another-user-account